# Switching between landscape and portrait causing trouble with media queries

Tags: ipad, media-queries

I'm currently working on my new website which is an adaptive one. I've setup two media queries for the iPad, one for portrait and one for landscape mode. They work fine on their own but not when switching from portrait to landscape. It displays the layout fine but only zoomed out. The other way around is fine so what could be the problem?

I'm using the mobile HTML5 boilerplate as the base which has the viewport issue already covered. That was the first thing that I thought causing the trouble.

The media queries:

```
/* iPads (landscape) ---------- */ 
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */ 
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
```

Also a live preview is available at nielspilonwebdesign.nl/dev/niels (Still work in progress)

Answer (score 0):

Your test link is broken right now.

Aside from that, you have (orientation: portrait) in your landscape media query. Also, is there a reason you're using device-width in your media queries instead of just width? I think your media queries are currently too specific and tied to device contraints, which is likely causing the weird rendering you're seeing.